# SQLITE3 store text and numbers in the same column

Tags: sqlite

In the SQLITE3 Docu you can find:

"SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system. In SQLite, the datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its container. The dynamic type system of SQLite is backwards compatible with the more common static type systems of other database engines in the sense that SQL statements that work on statically typed databases should work the same way in SQLite. However, the dynamic typing in SQLite allows it to do things which are not possible in traditional rigidly typed databases."

I have a column with different values some are integer, some float and some text. I use BLOB als storage class and it works fine. But i'm a little suspicious of this solution. Is this the right way to store numbers and text in the same column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR; you are not doing it wrong, but I also think you are not doing what you think you are doing.

I don't think you are using a BLOB storage class, but a BLOB type affinity. [In SQLite there are 2 concepts of datatype](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Storage class, and type affinity.

Storage class is the way a given value is stored in memory, it describes how bit patterns represent values. E.g. while numerically equal, the integer 1 and the floating point 1.0 are represented by very different bit patterns (at least in the memory, but curiously "As an internal optimization, small floating point values with no fractional component and stored in columns with REAL affinity are written to disk as integers").
There are 5 storage classes, NULL, INTEGER, REAL, TEXT, and BLOB.

Type affinity on the other hand, is not a value- but a column-level concept. Type affinity is a characteristic of a given column. There are also 5 type affinities, NUMBER, INTEGER, REAL, TEXT, and BLOB.

The first thing you might notice, is that there is no 1-1 mapping between storage classes and affinities. That's because they are indeed almost completely unrelated. Consider the following

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE Test(A TEXT, B BLOB, C REAL);
sqlite> INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('text', 'also a text', 'another one');
sqlite> INSERT INTO Test VALUES (10, 10.1, 10.11111111111111111111111);
sqlite> SELECT A, TYPEOF(A), B, TYPEOF(B), C, TYPEOF(C) FROM Test;
text|text|also a text|text|another one|text
10|text|10.1|real|10.1111111111111|real
```

As you can see, I defined the columns with types TEXT, BLOB, and REAL. [Those are the affinities](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#determination_of_column_affinity). But I was able to insert values of different types into them, regardless of their affinities. E.g. column C now both stores 'another one', of storage class TEXT, and 10.1111111111111 of storage class REAL.

Normally you should not be too concerned about storage classes, as you can see from my example, SQLite just automatically and correctly inferred them from the data I inserted.
Type affinity is more important. That's what describes how your data is compared, sorted, how it's uniqueness is determined. E.g.

```
sqlite> CREATE Table T(A TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO T VALUES ('1'), (2), (0.0);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY A ASC;
0.0
1
2
sqlite> CREATE TABLE R(A REAL);
sqlite> INSERT INTO R VALUES ('1'), (2), (0.0);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM R ORDER BY A ASC;
0.0
1.0
2.0
sqlite> CREATE TABLE B(A BLOB);
sqlite> INSERT INTO B VALUES ('1'), (2), (0.0);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM B ORDER BY A ASC;
0.0
2
1
```

So for practical purposes, it is more closely related to your intuitive idea of a datatype. Think about what your data **means**, and choose the affinity accordingly. If you store your values in a column of BLOB affinity, a bitwise comparison will be used on them. If this is what you want, go for it. But if you want a lexicographic comparison you need TEXT affinity, or if you want to do the comparisons based on the numerical values your data represents, then e.g. REAL.